# Hi, I am using Drupal 9 and on a request in network tab jQuery 3.5.1 sends another contextual render call. Any reason of this call?

Tags: drupal, jquery-3, drupal-9

I am using Drupal 9 and on a request in network tab jQuery 3.5.1 sends another contextual render call. Any reason of this call?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the action of module **Contextual Links** in Drupal core. It call to `/contextual/render` route for rendered data, then replace them to placeholders on the page.

To see more details what this module does, you can read [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/contextual).